# Is the space complexity linear if I am simply performing constant time operations on each character of a string? Also reversing the string?

Tags: python, time-complexity, space-complexity

I am solving the following question on Leetcode: https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-remove-to-make-valid-parentheses/

My question is around the `TIME & SPACE complexity` of my solution:

```
def minRemoveToMakeValid(s: str) -> str:
    count = 0
    pointer = 0
    while pointer < len(s):  # points to the last char of s
        if count >= 0:
            if s[pointer] == "(":
                count += 1
                pointer += 1
            elif s[pointer] == ")":
                count -= 1
                if count >=0:
                    pointer +=1
            else:
                pointer +=1
        else:
            if s[pointer] == ")":
                s = s.replace(s[pointer], " ", 1)
                count += 1
                pointer +=1

    if count > 0:
        s = s[::-1]
        s = s.replace("(", "", count)
        s = s[::-1]
    s = s.replace(" ", "")

    return s
```

In short, I am iterating through a string s, and performing an individual task to each character, which takes constant time.

I do NOT store the string in any data structure, so I am performing operations directly on the input.

Am I correct in saying that the `TIME complexity is O(n)`, where n is the length of the string, and the `SPACE complexity is O(1)` ; since I am using constant space? It is more the space complexity that I was unsure about.

Comment: `s = s.replace(s[pointer], " ", 1)` this does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Hi orlp, I used it for a question on Leetcode and the tests there are quite comprehensive and it passed all the tests, which part in particular did you mean when you mention it doesn't do what I think it does? Thanks for the comment

Comment: It simply replaces the first `s[pointer]` in the string with a space, and has to search all the way from the start of the string to find it. It's no different than if you had written `s.replace(')', ' ', 1)` in that context.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the time complexity is O(N) and space complexity is O(1)

Comment: Are you sure? Because I read that when you replace items in a string or modify items in a string, the whole string gets 'rebuilt' because strings are immutable. And in the worst case, we replace every element in the string, so wouldn't the time complexity be O(N^2)?